# Unable to retrieve search results from server side : Facebook Graph API using Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing some simple Python + FB Graph training on my own, and I faced a weird problem:

```
import time
import sys
import urllib2
import urllib
from json import loads

base_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q="
post_id = None
post_type = None
user_id = None 
message = None
created_time = None

def doit(hour):
    page = 1
    search_term = "\"Plastic Planet\""
    encoded_search_term = urllib.quote(search_term)
    print encoded_search_term
    type="&type=post"
    url = "%s%s%s" % (base_url,encoded_search_term,type)
    print url
    while(1):

        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print e
        finally:
            pass   

        content = response.read()
        content = loads(content)

        print "=================================="
        for c in content["data"]:
            print c
            print "****************************************"

        try:
            content["paging"]
            print "current URL"
            print url
            print "next page!------------"
            url = content["paging"]["next"]
            print url
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            pass

        """
        print "new URL is ======================="
        print url
        print "==================================" 
        """
        print url
```

What I'm trying to do here is to automatically page through the search results,
but trying for content["paging"]["next"]

But the weird thing is that no data is returned; I received the following:

```
{"data":[]}
```

Even in the very first loop.

But when I copied the URL into a browser, a lot of results were returned.

I've also tried a version with my access token and th same thing happens.

+++++++++++++++++++EDITED and SIMPLIFIED++++++++++++++++++

ok thanks to TryPyPy, here's the simplified and edited version of my previous question:

Why is that:

```
   import urllib2
       url = "https://graph.facebook.com/searchq=%22Plastic+Planet%22&type=post&limit=25&until=2010-12-29T19%3A54%3A56%2B0000"
       response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
       print response.read()
```

result in `{"data":[]}` ?

But the same url produces a lot of data in a browser?

Comment: OK, was able to reproduce. I think your question can be simplified to: why does `import urllib2; url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22Plastic+Planet%22&type=post&limit=25&until=2010-12-29T19%3A54%3A56%2B0000"; response = urllib2.urlopen(url); print response.read()` result in `{"data":[]}`, but the same URL in a browser gives lots of output?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I've simplified the question. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: I've had no luck diagnosing this, but I saw that FB was sending cookies back (`print response.headers`). Maybe you can open two different browsers, one with cookies blocked and one allowing all, then get a newly created URL and see if the lack of cookies support is to blame. Sorry for not testing this myself.

Comment: Scratch that, it seems that adding the `Accept-Language` header magically solves this.

Comment: ok i'll try adding in the Accept-Language header and get back to u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trial and error using Chrome (where I got lots of data) and Firefox (where I got the empty response) made me zero on the 'Accept-Language' header. Other modifications are supposedly only cosmetic, but I'm not sure about the CookieJar.

```
import time
import sys
import urllib2
import urllib
from json import loads
import cookielib

base_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q="
post_id = None
post_type = None
user_id = None 
message = None
created_time = None

jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
opener.addheaders = [
    ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8'),]

def doit(hour):
    page = 1
    search_term = "\"Plastic Planet\""
    encoded_search_term = urllib.quote(search_term)
    print encoded_search_term
    type="&type=post"
    url = "%s%s%s" % (base_url,encoded_search_term,type)

    print url

    data = True
    while data:
        response = opener.open(url)
        opener.addheaders += [
            ('Referer', url) ]

        content = response.read()
        content = loads(content)

        print "=================================="
        for c in content["data"]:
            print c.keys()
        print "****************************************"

        if "paging" in content:
            print "current URL"
            print url
            print "next page!------------"
            url = content["paging"]["next"]
            print url
        else:
            print content
            print url
            data = False

doit(1)
```

Here's a cleaned up, minimal working version:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from json import loads
import cookielib

def doit(search_term, base_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q="):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8')]

    encoded_search_term = urllib.quote(search_term)
    type="&type=post"
    url = "%s%s%s" % (base_url,encoded_search_term,type)

    print encoded_search_term
    print url

    data = True
    while data:
        response = opener.open(url)

        content = loads(response.read())

        print "=================================="
        for c in content["data"]:
            print c.keys()
        print "****************************************"

        if "paging" in content:
            url = content["paging"]["next"]
        else:
            print "Empty response"
            print content
            data = False

doit('"Plastic Planet"')
```

Comment: hey, it works!. I was wondering how did you discover that by adding Accept Language header solve the issue?

Comment: I thought there had to be a difference causing the lack of data on Python, so I started adding random headers to the urllib2 opener. That didn't work, so I opened Firefox to use Live HTTP headers and copy all headers... but Firefox didn't show any more data than Python, while Chrome did. So I used Chrome's Dev Tools to see what headers it sent, and pasted each one into FF's Live HTTP headers until I got lots of data in FF too, which happened with Accept-Language. Using that on Python worked fine too :)